# A href in header sections are not acting as link and vertical height is not 100vh

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

I am working on a small website front end where everything is going according to plan but my a hrefs on header is not clickable. I think there is some CSS problem. Here I will add html and css of the project.

Header links for home team books etx are given href in html but its not clickable.

And also am getting vertical height getting repeated with scroll, I don't want that. How do I get rid of it?

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: Century Gothic;
}

/** header **/

.main{    
    align-items: center;
    }

ul {
    margin-top: 15px;
    list-style-type: none;
    float: right;
    }

ul li {
    display: inline-block;    
}

ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: #000;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    color: #b61e83;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    transition: 0.6s ease;}

ul li a:hover{
    background-color: #ff4562;
    color: #000;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

ul li.active a{
    background-color: #b61e83;
    color: #fff;
}

#top {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    z-index: -1;
}

#bottom {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    z-index: -1;
}

/** body **/

body {

    padding: 50px 100px;
    align-content: center;
    background-image: linear-gradient(111.37738709038058deg, rgba(43, 45, 78, 1) 1.557291666666667%, rgba(225, 20, 139, 1) 101.34895833333333%);
    /*linear-gradient(114.50890543382422deg, rgba(28, 0, 66, 1) 1.6731770833333333%, rgba(0, 235, 215, 1) 97.94270833333331%);*/
    display: inherit;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

/** home text **/
.hometext {
    position: absolute;
    right: 25%;
    top: 40%;
    color: #fff;
    width: 500px;

}

.quote {
    position: relative;
    justify-content: center;
}

/** clock css **/

.clock {
    position: absolute;
    top: 25%;
    left: 18vw;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background: url(../images/_clock.png);
    background-size: cover;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0 -25px +25px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05),
        inset 0 -25px +25px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05),
        0 25px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05),
        inset 0 25px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}


.clock:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    z-index: 1000;
}

.clock .hour,
.clock .min,
.clock .sec {
    position: absolute;
}

.clock .hour,
.hr {
    width: 260px;
    height: 200px;
}

.clock .min,
.mn {
    width: 250px;
    height: 300px;
}

.clock .sec,
.sc {
    width: 330px;
    height: 330px;
}

.hr,
.mn,
.sc {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    /*align-items: center;*/
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.hr:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 12px;
    height: 90px;
    background: #ff105e;
    z-index: 10;
    border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
}

.mn:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 4px;
    height: 150px;
    background: #fff;
    z-index: 11;
    border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
}

.sc:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 2px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #fff;
    z-index: 12;
    border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
}

/** animated background **/

.circles {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.circles li {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    list-style: none;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    animation: animate 25s linear infinite;
    bottom: -150px;

}

.circles li:nth-child(1) {
    left: 25%;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    animation-delay: 0s;
}


.circles li:nth-child(2) {
    left: 10%;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    animation-delay: 2s;
    animation-duration: 12s;
}

.circles li:nth-child(3) {
    left: 70%;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    animation-delay: 4s;
}

.circles li:nth-child(4) {
    left: 40%;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    animation-delay: 0s;
    animation-duration: 18s;
}

.circles li:nth-child(5) {
    left: 65%;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    animation-delay: 0s;
}

.circles li:nth-child(6) {
    left: 75%;
    width: 110px;
    height: 110px;
    animation-delay: 3s;
}

.circles li:nth-child(7) {
    left: 35%;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    animation-delay: 7s;
}

.circles li:nth-child(8) {
    left: 50%;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    animation-delay: 15s;
    animation-duration: 45s;
}

.circles li:nth-child(9) {
    left: 20%;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    animation-delay: 2s;
    animation-duration: 35s;
}

.circles li:nth-child(10) {
    left: 85%;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    animation-delay: 0s;
    animation-duration: 11s;
}



@keyframes animate {

    0% {
        transform: translateY(0) rotate(0deg);
        opacity: 1;
        border-radius: 0;
    }

    100% {
        transform: translateY(-1000px) rotate(720deg);
        opacity: 0;
        border-radius: 50%;
    }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Javascript Clack UI Dark</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cabin+Sketch:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>

    <!-- Head elements -->
    
    <div class="main">
              <ul>
                  <li class="active"><a href="#"><b>Home</b></a></li>
                  <li><a href="#"><b>Team</b></a></li>
                  <li><a href="#"><b>Exams</b></a></li>
                  <li><a href="#"><b>Books</b></a></li>
                  <li><a href="#"><b>Demo</b></a></li>
                  <li><a href="www.neram.co.in"><b>Alumnus</b></a></li>
                  <li><a href="#"><b>Contact</b></a></li>                      
              
              </ul>          
          </div> 

    <header>
        <img src="images/web-yellow.png">        
        
        <!-- SVG cuts -->


        <svg id="top" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1144 107.17">
            <defs>
                <style>
                    .cls-1 {
                        fill: #fff;
                    }

                </style>
            </defs>
            <path class="cls-1" d="M221.5-.5s2.26,0,6.49.19C261.54.77,419,7.31,557.5,37.5c156,34,299,65,474,69s334-66,334-66V-.5Z" transform="translate(-221.5 0.5)" />
        </svg>

        <svg id="bottom" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1129 334">
            <defs>
                <style>
                    .cls-1 {
                        fill: #fff;
                    }

                </style>
            </defs>
            <path class="cls-1" d="M237,768s394.36-9.88,698.58-72.73S1366,434,1366,434V768Z" transform="translate(-237 -434)" />
        </svg>



    </header>


    <!-- HTML for clock -->

    <div class="clock">
        <div class="hour">
            <div class="hr" id="hr"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="min">
            <div class="mn" id="mn"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="sec">
            <div class="sc" id="sc"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Header paragraphy -->

    <div class="hometext">
        <h3>neram | classes</h3><br>
        <p>Meeting right person at right time will change everything in life. It happended for us.</p><br>

        <p class="quote">“We are one of that kind” </p><br>

        <p>Hence we name our initiative as neram ( Time ). neram is not a typical NATA coaching center, we are architects & Designers from various parts of the world working for the betterment of next generation of architects. We belive our NATA coaching is the starting point for that.</p>

    </div>

    <!-- Animates shapes -->

    <div class="area">
        <ul class="circles">
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <!-- java scrtipt for clock -->

    <script type="text/javascript">
        const deg = 6;
        const hr = document.querySelector('#hr');
        const mn = document.querySelector('#mn');
        const sc = document.querySelector('#sc');

        setInterval(() => {

            let day = new Date();
            let hh = day.getHours() * 30;
            let mm = day.getMinutes() * deg;
            let ss = day.getSeconds() * deg;

            hr.style.transform = `rotateZ(${(hh)+(mm/12)}deg)`;
            mn.style.transform = `rotateZ(${mm}deg)`;
            sc.style.transform = `rotateZ(${ss}deg)`;

        })

    </script>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Links are alright. It's just layer of class="circles" that is in front of the nav.
Please try to add position relative and z-index to your CSS (code below) =>

```
   .main {
        align-items: center;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 9998!important;
     }
```

For background repeat issue add these two properties to the body in CSS =>

```
body {
 height: 100vh;
 overflow: hidden;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks alot, my height problem haven't solved gradients getting repeated ..

Answer (score 0):

In href you need to put the path where you want it to direct like you did in alumnus.

```
href="http://www.example.com"
```

You used min-height, that tells it to be at least 100vh but it is no limit so it can exceed 100vh. Try also adding a max-height.

```
 Max-height:100vh;
```

Comment: "#" can be used for dummy links right ? Even alumnus is not working.

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle or a screenshot to see the error?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aXUbdXETiPqzqbFhjiEJydpsKHjoVHzA/view?usp=sharing here is the screenshot ... my link is also not clickable

Comment: Could you inspect the links to see if they have an element overlayed?